# How do I reset my MIDI device?

Tags: 14.04, sound, usb, midi

I have my MIDI enabled digital piano connected via USB. To play .mid files I am using pmidi. Sometimes when I stop playback (using ^C) some notes are still playing. I know that's because of how MIDI works. To make these notes stop playing I have to switch off and on my piano. That is inconvenient and bad for the device.

Is there a way to reset my MIDI device in software from command line? There is a MIDI command which does that, but I can't find a way to send it to the device.

Comment: Try the following command:modprobe snd-seq-midi

Comment: @vembutech No, it doesn't work. I've even tried using that command while playing a file and there wasn't any effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a .mid file containing All Sounds Off (120) or All Notes Off (123) controller messages for all channels.

Alternatively, use a GM Reset SysEx message (F0 7E 7F 09 01 F7).

If you cannot create .mid files, you can send commands directly with `amidi`:

```
amidi -p hw:X -S "f07e7f0901f7"
```

(Use `amidi -l` to see which port name to use.)